# Why can't I view Omegle's HTTP request/response headers?

Tags: http, header, protocols

I'm trying to write a small program that I can talk to Omegle strangers via command line for school. However I'm having some issues, I'm sure I could solve the problem if I could view the headers sent however if you talk to a stranger on Omegle while Live HTTP Headers (or a similar plug-in or program) is running the headers don't show. Why is this? Are they not sending HTTP headers and using a different protocol instead?

I'm really lost with this, any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

I had success in writing a command line Omegle chat client. However it is hardcoded in C for POSIX and curses.

I'm not sure what exactly your problem is, maybe it's just something with your method of reverse engineering Omegle's protocol. If you want to make a chat client, use a network packet analyzer such as Wireshark (or if you're on a POSIX system I recommend tcpdump), study exactly what data is sent and received during a chat session and have your program emulate what the default web client is doing. Another option is to de-compile/reverse engineer the default web client itself, which would be a more thorough method but more complicated.